# How to move a column name to next column in ror application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have added a checkbox feature in my RoR application, I have a single column (Content) in my table, after adding a checkbox feature the checkboxes are displayed in the content column and records in the content column are moved to the next. How do I move the column name and display above the records?

I am a beginner, Please help me to improve my RoR learning.

My Index.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"> </p>

<h1>Messages</h1>
<%= form_tag messages_path, method: :delete do %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "message_ids[]", message.id%></td>
        <td><%= message.content %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
        <!-- <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td> -->
      </tr>
    <% end %> 
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= submit_tag :Delete,class: 'btn' %>
</br>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= link_to  'New Message', new_message_path %> 
</br>
```

Comment: You want the content first and then checkbox should appear. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an html problem, not a ror problem.

Your table-headers must match the row-data, and you have not added a header for the new checkbox column.

Do something like:

```
<tr>
  <th>Checkbox</th>
  <th>Content</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
```

If you want nothing in the table header for this checkbox-column, then leave it empty eg:

```
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Content</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
```

and they will align properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) @Taryn East

Answer (score 1):

Please add Checkbox in the header and This is an HTML problem, not a ROR problem.

```
<tr>
   <th>Checkbox</th>
   <th>Content</th>
   <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
```